# How would I figure out what $(x,y)$ a cannon should aim at, so that it's cannonball would hit a different $(x,y)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Sorry if the title is unclear, I am not well versed in physics.

Hi! I'm trying to program an artillery piece in this game I am playing to automatically orient itself. I do not however, know what calculations to use to get it to aim at an angle that would lead it to hit a target.

I have access to:

Target's X and Y

Game's Gravity ( 54.939 m/s2 )

Initial Velocity ( 20.1 m/s2 )

Problem, I cannot imput an angle to orient the cannon, how can I convert this angle to an X,Y co-ordinate that , if the cannon is looking at it would be oriented in the right angle? (assuming the cannon is ground level)

Comment: if you already know the angle just do some permutation of cannonPosition +/- sin/cos(angle) depending on the game's coordinate system, and this is a mathematics question, not physics